# iterar sobre objeto lm en r

Tags: r, rstudio, machine-learning

**new_dataset** es un dataset con 19 variables, lo que intento hacer es hacer un modelo que logre el mejor ajuste siguiendo esta metodología: primero que quede fija la variable dependiente Y. Segundo que pruebe las variables desde ds[,1] hasta ds[,19]. Tercero que cuando la variable tenga un p-valor por debajo de 0.05 la deje en el modelo de lo contrario que la elimine.

```
for (i in new_dataset) {
  prueba_modelo <- lm(data = new_dataset, formula = 
                        ds$Y~ i) 
  p_val_prueba <- data.frame(summary(prueba_modelo)$coefficients[ ,4])

    if(p_val_prueba[i,1]<0.05){
        prueba_modelo <- lm(data = new_dataset, formula = 
                         ds$Y ~ i) 
  } else {

  prueba_modelo <- lm(data = new_dataset, formula = 
                          ds$regresion_otto.ir ~ i+1)

  }

 }
```

Comment: ¿Estás haciendo un ejercicio o estás buscando solucionar un problema concreto de predicción/inferencia? Lo pregunto porque se puede hacer lo que quieres, pero **no** es un buen procedimiento para seleccionar predictores Una alternativa mucho mejor en todo sentido son los modelos de regresión penalizada (lasso o ridge) implementados en R en el paquete `glmnet`. En https://www.rpubs.com/Joaquin_AR/242707 encuentras una descripción del uso de `glmnet` en sus variantes. No solo dan mejores resultados, también son óptimos matemáticamente y resuelven el problema mucho más rápido.

Comment: Es un problema concreto de predicción. Me vendría muy bien conocer esas técnicas.